# how to get all the values in a dictionary with the same key?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like below and I want to get all the values in a dictionary with the same key,currenlty when I say `modules[module]`I only get the last value?

```
modules = {'acer.nak':'kaui.nak','acer.nak':'maui.nak','acer.nak':'nihau.nak'}
module = 'acer.nak'
print modules[module]
```

OUTPUT:

```
nihau.nak
```

EXPECTED OUPUT:

```
['kaui.nak','maui.nak','nihau.nak']
```

Comment: First of all you should understand about python dict, your dict is not a valid one,because dicts cannot have duplicate keys .

Comment: Although your dict construction doesn't throw any syntax errors, a Python dict can have only ONE value per key, because Python doesn't allow duplicate keys as said by @VikasDamodar above.

Maybe what you need is to have a list for the desired key:
`{'acer.nak': ['kaui.nak', 'maui.nak', 'nihau.nak']}`